# How to change the output message of a search?

Tags: regex, search, vim, output

I would like to change the output message when a search is done.

p.e. when I do a search with a very long regex and nothing has been found vim returns the message `E486: Pattern not found: .... very long regex code ...`

I would like to capture the output and change this message.
How can I do this?

Comment: please write you name if you downvote my question and tell me why you downvote it. tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:s[ubstitute]` command has the `/e` flag for suppressing errors but, AFAIK, even `:silent /foo` won't suppress that error message. Well, you don't want to suppress it, anyway, you want to "capture" it and show something else.

Like every language, vimscript has its own `try/catch`. You can read about it in `:h :try` and further down the page.

```
try
  /foo
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E486/
  let @n = v:exception
  echo "No luck!"
endtry
```

You could wrap your `try/catch` in a function that you `noremap` to `/`

Comment: Thank you Romainl, do you know how to put the content of catch to the clipboard (or a register)?

Comment: It didn't capture anything till yet but I'll find it. Does it work also with `let @/ = 'foo'` ?

Comment: The code above works, here. I have "Vim(append):E486: Pattern not found: foo" in register `n` and `No luck!` echoed on the commandline. How do you plan to use `let @/ = 'foo'`?

Comment: I think it is because at the beginning I used `/foo` (gives an error if no pattern is found) and then I put all code in a script  `let @/ = 'foo'`. This doesn't give an error at all if no pattern is found. I didn't know that there are no error messages when I use a search code in a script.

Comment: `let @/ = 'foo'` doesn't perform any search: it replaces the content of the search register with `foo`. The only effect it has is that you get `foo` next time you try to re-use the latest search pattern instead of the actual search pattern that was used.

Comment: btw ..how can you execute the search `let @/`?

Comment: `let @{register} = 'foo'` is used to change the value of `{register}`. `"/` is the search register, it contains your latest search pattern. `let @/ = 'foo'` replaces the previous search pattern with `foo`. Assuming your previous pattern was `bar`, hitting `n` should jump you to the next `foo` instead of the next `bar`. Another good use of the previous search pattern is building your pattern with `/` before doing a substitution and then doing `:%s//bar` to reuse that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about catching the Error message in your vimscript.

Then you may want to check out `catch` : `:h catch`

```
                    *:cat* *:catch* *E603* *E604* *E605*
:cat[ch] /{pattern}/    The following commands until the next |:catch|,
            |:finally|, or |:endtry| that belongs to the same
            |:try| as the ":catch" are executed when an exception
            matching {pattern} is being thrown and has not yet
            been caught by a previous ":catch".  Otherwise, these
            commands are skipped.
            When {pattern} is omitted all errors are caught.
            Examples: >
        :catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/    " catch interrupts (CTRL-C)
        :catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E/    " catch all Vim errors
        :catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:/ " catch errors and interrupts
        :catch /^Vim(write):/       " catch all errors in :write
        :catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E123/ " catch error E123
        :catch /my-exception/       " catch user exception
        :catch /.*/         " catch everything
        :catch              " same as /.*/
```

in `try` block do the search, then you could catch the error message, and do whatever you want.